# Best way for embedding vector gfx in MS PowerPoint?

Tags: powerpoint, vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator

What is a good technique to export/import vector grafiks from Adobe Illustrator to MS PowerPoint?

Comment: What do you mean by not embedded flawlessly? PP2010 will accept EMF files by default.

Comment: As I recall, you want to scale them up relatively large in Illustrator before saving as EMF.  Curves sometimes turn into a series of straight line segments; the larger the drawing, the more line segments you get, so the smoother it looks in PPT.

Comment: Does not make me happy. We always have the problem that edges are not smooth. Best way until now is to render as PNG and import as pixel graphic. No good...

Comment: "Does not make me happy" as a comment does not make me happy.  ;-) Which of the other comments does it refer to?

Comment: Toyours. Scaling them up didn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG file would be the best and link to the file. Be sure to make sure your links are all together when you hand it off.